# More formal alternative for "called"

Tags: synonyms, formality

Is the word "called" used appropriately? The following sentences come from motivation letters and thesis.

> I had an opportunity to attend a seminar at an agency **called** XYZ Group.
>
> I studied at a secondary school **called** gymnasium. (gymnasium is the sort of the secondary school students that enter at ~13 and leave at ~18.)
>
> This technique is also informally **called** The White Bear.

I can't help but feel that "called" sounds quite informal. Is it so?
If so, can I substitute it with something more formal?

Comment: What do dictionaries and thesauruses offer as synonyms for "called"?

Comment: *called* is not informal. *Called* is what it is called.

Comment: 'referred to as' is certainly not informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it’s not so much formal or informal, as usage. As an educated native (British) English speaker of a certain age, I would avoid ‘called’ in the first two of your examples because it just doesn’t feel right. Possible ways of rewriting are:

> I had an opportunity to attend a seminar at an agency — the XYZ Group.

.

> I studied at a *type of* secondary school, *for which the German name is* ‘Gymnasium’…

or

> I studied at a *type of* secondary school, *known in German as a* ‘Gymnasium’…

Otherwise the suggestion of @EdwinAshworth of using ‘referred’ is more formal (or sounds more posh having more syllables and being derived from Latin):

> I studied at a *type of* secondary school, *referred to in German as a* ‘Gymnasium’…

In the third example ‘called’ is, in my opinion, exactly right.

(Be careful with your capitalization of German nouns ;-) )